# Mysql stored procedure for n*m inserts

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm working with mysql stored procedure and I am pretty new, so need a little help from experts.

I have a `table A` which has some 500+ rows and a `table B` with 50 rows. What I want to do is write a simple stored procedure which inserts 500*50 rows in this new table (1 row from `table A` should match to all 50 rows of `table B`. This should happen for all the rows in `table A`).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @shehary well im new, so far i tried writing simple ones from mysql tutorial but i dont understand how to do the loop in it like takes 1 row from A and maps to all in B

Comment: post your code snippet what ever your tried and we will take it from there and provide possible best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to achieve that:

```
INSERT INTO TableC (SELECT * FROM TableA CROSS JOIN TableB)
```

where `TableC` is your new table.

Comment: But i dont want all the columns from these tables. Just a few hand picked ones, can i still achieve it this way?

Comment: You definitely can. Just replace the `*` by the columns that you want. For example, replace it by `TableA.Col1, TableA.Col5, TableB.Col2`.

Comment: INSERT INTO TableC (SELECT * FROM TableA CROSS JOIN TableB) worked after removing value. Thanks!